# Facebook social comment plugin loads too slowly in react single page app

Tags: reactjs, facebook-comments

I have a react class component where I need to load the facebook social comment plugin so that users can leave their comment. I've written the code like this:

**This is the componentDidMount function:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      window.FB.init({
        appId: getConfigarationByKey('fb_app_id'),
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v8.0'
      })
      window.FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', this.stopSpinner)
    }
    var sdkSrc = ''
    if (localStorage.getItem('lang') === 'en')
      sdkSrc = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v8.0'
    else sdkSrc = '//connect.facebook.net/bn_IN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v8.0'
    ;(function (d, s, id) {
      const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return
      }
      const js = d.createElement(s)
      js.id = id
      js.src = sdkSrc
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
    })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    if (window.FB && window.FB.XFBML) {
      window.FB.XFBML.parse()
    }
  }
```

**And when I change route, I clean up the comment plugin codes like this:**

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
    if (window.FB) delete window.FB
    document.getElementById('fb-root').outerHTML = ''
    document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk').outerHTML = ''
  }
```

**And Finally I wrote the html as per it's suggested in the official docs**

```
render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardContent>
          <div
            className="fb-comments"
            data-colorscheme="dark"
            data-href={window.location.href}
            data-numposts="5"
            data-width="100%"
          ></div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    )
  }
```

That is all. The comment plugin loads and works fine, but it takes almost 30 seconds to load on the page which is a very bad user experience. Can anyone please help me why it is taking this much time to load ? And how I can improve it. Thank you.